# Getting error 400 on POST request

Tags: android, python, http, kotlin

So, I've got a simple Python server that listens to POST request with simple text and an Android app that should send the request. I've got code 400: Bad Request all the times.
Here's my code:

```
fun post (url: URL, data: String) : String
{
    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection

    connection.doOutput = true
    connection.doInput = true
    connection.connectTimeout = 5000
    connection.readTimeout = 5000
    connection.requestMethod = "POST"

    connection.setRequestProperty("ImageBase64", data)        

    connection.connect()

    val rcode = connection.responseCode
    //val response = connection.responseMessage

    return rcode.toString()
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPD: I am sending a Base64-encoded picture as a string.

Here's my server code:

```
import base64
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def imageget():
    image_base64 = request.form['ImageBase64']

    with open("C:/CatImage.png", "wb") as Image:
        Image.write(base64.decodebytes(bytes(image_base64, 'utf-8')))
    return 'Success!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: what is your url try it in postman first.

Comment: We don't know what data your server is expecting, nor what data you're posting. I don't see any "Content-Type" header which may be the issue.